# Remove a pair of chars in a string next to each other

Tags: java, string, replace, duplicates, char

In an interview, I have faced one problem, and I'm unable to find the logic for dynamic input.

Input: `abbcaddaee`

If This input is given, we have to remove pair of char, for example
`abbcaddaee`. Bold value will be removed, and output is `acaa`, then we have to do the same for this also, then `acaa`. The final output is `ac`.

Likewise have to do `n` number of iterations to remove these pairs of the same `char`.

Input: `aabbbcffjdddd` → `aabbbcffjdddd` → `bcj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *regexp* and a single *do-while loop*:

```java
String str = "abbcaddaee";

do {
    System.out.println(str);
} while (!str.equals(str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "")));
```

Output:

```
abbcaddaee
acaa
ac
```

Explanation:

- *regexp* `(.)\\1` - any character followed by the same character;
- `str = str.replaceAll(...)` - removes all duplicates and replaces current string;
- `!str.equals(...)` - checks *inequality* of the current string with itself, but without duplicates.

---

<sup>See also: [Iterate through a string and remove consecutive duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66943528/15551420)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex replacement here:

```java
String input = "aabbbcffjdddd";
String output = input.replaceAll("(.)\\1", "");
System.out.println(output);  // bcj
```

The regex pattern `(.)\1` matches any single character followed by that same character once.  We replace such matches with empty string, effectively removing them.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, But I have to satisfy another condition on it. we have to run this in a loop until, all the matches to be removed. 

Example :  
```aabbbcffjdddd```  ->  ```acaa```  ->  ```ac``` 

How can we decide this iteration count?

Comment: @SankarSiva so what prevents one from doing so using this code?

Comment: @SankarSiva Make all the requirements explicitly in the question

Comment: Thanks, guys. It's my mistake. I will correct myself in the future.

Thank you very much for the support :thumbsup

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution, I used the recursive method to give you the result you want.

For Pattern:

```
1st Capturing Group (.)
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
```

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)\\1");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(removePairChar("abbcaddaee"));
        System.out.println(removePairChar("aabbbcffjdddd"));
    }

    public static String removePairChar(String input) {
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
        if(matchFound) {
            input = input.replaceAll(p.pattern(), "");
            return removePairChar(input);
        }
        return input;
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ac
bcj
```

Comment: Using recursion here is totally unnecessary as `String#replaceAll` already does a global replacement.  This is not the most efficient way to use regex here.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use Stack. In this case we will have O(n) complexity as opposed to `while + replaceAll`

1. Loop through char codes, if char code is not present in stack push it
2. If the stack head equals to the current char code pop it

```java
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String... params) {
        System.out.println(Main.normalize("abbcaddaee"));
        System.out.println(Main.normalize("aabbbcffjdddd"));
    }

    private static String normalize(final String input) {
        final int length = Optional.ofNullable(input).map(String::length).orElse(0);
        if (length < 2) {
            return input;
        }

        Stack<Integer> buf = new Stack<Integer>();
        input.codePoints().forEach(code -> {
            if (buf.isEmpty() || buf.peek() != code) {
                buf.push(code);
            } else {
                buf.pop();
            }
        });

        return buf.stream().collect(
            StringBuilder::new,
            StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
            StringBuilder::append).
            toString();
    }
}
```